# How do I tell Agent Ransack to avoid a particular path/filename pattern?

Tags: windows, desktop-search, agent-ransack

I've started using [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) to search an entire directory at once looking for a particular string. The only issue I have with it so far is that if I'm searching in a Subversion working copy, it finds the string in the `.svn` folders, which of course is not what I want. Is there a way to tell it to ignore any directory named `.svn` as well as any subdirectories of a `.svn` directory?

Comment: It already knows, by default, to avoid `.git` directories. Just kidding :)

Answer (score 17):

Apparently you can exclude files now in the free version of Agent Ransack by using the following syntax:

```
NOT: *.dll; *.svn-base
```

Comment: yep - works a treat!

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in the free version. Your best bet is to make sure you include the file extension and then it'll exclude the svn-base files, e.g.

```
*.cs;*.vb
```

Answer (score 4):

As snowdude hinted [FileLocator Pro](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/) (which is the paid version of "[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/)"/"[FileLocator Lite](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite/)" same thing different name If you are willing to upgrade (or like me willing to persuade your boss it's a good investment!) then there is a feature specificity for this under [Persistent Search Filter](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/help/index.html?persistent_search_filters.htm) so once set it will always ignore ".svn", ".hg" and ".git"(for Yar!)

So if you have this version (or buy it) then you can click the little filter icon to the right of the "subfolders" tickbox ([see this pic](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/help/searchfilteractive.png)) and click *"Exclude SVN/HG/GIT/CVS meta data folders"* (even shows you the filter it uses so you can update it directly or copy it for other uses).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, if you turn on the File Name match by Regular Expression in the Tab Options. Then use a expression like **.*jsp$**,  this will exclude all SVN control files of the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Agent Ransack itself for this task.
To avoid specific directories (Ex: c:\Windows), update the field "Look in": "c:\; !C:\Windows"

!C:\Windows - This will exclude Windows directory from search criteria.